# In SQL Server, why there are duplicated DMVs in all database? Such as sys.databases

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

In SQL Server, there are some **DMV**s that appear in all databases and have the same content in it. What's the purpose of this approach? For example, the following 2 query will give the same result.

```
select *
from   master.sys.databases

select *
from   tempdb.sys.databases
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sys.databases only exists once (actually in the hidden resource database)

All you are doing above is switching db context temporarily by using a 3 part object name